# Change of light from not visible to visible

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, atomic-physics, frequency

Can light from infrared or UV change to visible light when it passes through some other material?

Comment: Fluorescence, phosphorescence, down conversion, Raman scattering, ...

Comment: Yes, but... Jon Custer gave you a lot of options, but they won't conserve momentum, so one can make a light field visible in a way, but it won't be preserved in a meaningful sense. Doppler effect would preserve the structure better, but it would require a very fast moving object, which we can't make, at least not, yet.

Comment: A specific material : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorophore